# Combine the two windows

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

The below programme is live straming on raspberry pi. The problem I am facing is that this code is resulting in forming two different windows, that is one for live streaming and one for controls (i.e contrast, brightness, etc). Please help me to combine this two windows, forming one GUI application.
Thank you.

```
import picamera
import Tkinter
import time
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from threading import Thread
import io
import sys

RQS_0=0
RQS_QUIT=1
RQS_CAPTURE=2
rqs=RQS_0

def camHandler():
    global rqs
    rqs = RQS_0

    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    #stream = io.BytesIO()

    #set default
    camera.sharpness = 0
    camera.contrast = 0
    camera.brightness = 50
    camera.saturation = 0
    camera.ISO = 0
    camera.video_stabilization = False
    camera.exposure_compensation = 0
    camera.exposure_mode = 'auto'
    camera.meter_mode = 'average'
    camera.awb_mode = 'auto'
    camera.image_effect = 'none'
    camera.color_effects = None
    #camera.rotation = 0
    camera.rotation = 270
    camera.hflip = False
    camera.vflip = False
    camera.crop = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    #camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
    camera.resolution = (400, 300)
    #end of set default
    #camera.start_preview()

    while rqs != RQS_QUIT:
        if rqs == RQS_CAPTURE:
            print("Capture")
            rqs=RQS_0
            timeStamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
            jpgFile='img_'+timeStamp+'.jpg'
            camera.resolution = (2592, 1944)    #set photo size
            camera.capture(jpgFile)
            camera.resolution = (400, 300)      #resume preview size
            labelCapVal.set(jpgFile)
        else:
            #set parameter
            camera.sharpness = scaleSharpness.get()
            camera.contrast = scaleContrast.get()
            camera.brightness = scaleBrightness.get()
            camera.saturation = scaleSaturation.get()
            camera.exposure_compensation = scaleExpCompensation.get()

            stream = io.BytesIO()
            camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')
            stream.seek(0)
            tmpImage = Image.open(stream)
            tmpImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tmpImage)
            previewPanel.configure(image = tmpImg)
            #sleep(0.5)

    print("Quit")        
    #camera.stop_preview()

def startCamHandler():
    camThread = Thread(target=camHandler)
    camThread.start()

def quit():
    global rqs
    rqs=RQS_QUIT

    global tkTop
    tkTop.destroy()

def capture():
    global rqs
    rqs = RQS_CAPTURE
    labelCapVal.set("capturing")

tkTop = Tkinter.Tk()
tkTop.wm_title("Raspberry Pi Camera")
tkTop.geometry('800x500')

previewWin = Tkinter.Toplevel(tkTop)
previewWin.title('Preview')
previewWin.geometry('400x300')
previewPanel = Tkinter.Label(previewWin)
previewPanel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

tkButtonQuit = Tkinter.Button(
    tkTop, text="Quit", command=quit)
tkButtonQuit.pack()

tkButtonCapture = Tkinter.Button(
    tkTop, text="Capture", command=capture)
tkButtonCapture.pack()

SCALE_WIDTH = 780;

labelCapVal = Tkinter.StringVar()
Tkinter.Label(tkTop, textvariable=labelCapVal).pack()

scaleSharpness = Tkinter.Scale(
    tkTop,
    from_=-100, to=100,
    length=SCALE_WIDTH,
    orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
    label="sharpness")
scaleSharpness.set(0)
scaleSharpness.pack(anchor=Tkinter.CENTER)

scaleContrast = Tkinter.Scale(
    tkTop,
    from_=-100, to=100,
    length=SCALE_WIDTH,
    orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
    label="contrast")
scaleContrast.set(0)
scaleContrast.pack(anchor=Tkinter.CENTER)

scaleBrightness = Tkinter.Scale(
    tkTop,
    from_=0, to=100,
    length=SCALE_WIDTH,
    orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
    label="brightness")
scaleBrightness.set(50)
scaleBrightness.pack(anchor=Tkinter.CENTER)

scaleSaturation = Tkinter.Scale(
    tkTop,
    from_=-100, to=100,
    length=SCALE_WIDTH,
    orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
    label="saturation")
scaleSaturation.set(0)
scaleSaturation.pack(anchor=Tkinter.CENTER)

scaleExpCompensation = Tkinter.Scale(
    tkTop,
    from_=-25, to=25,
    length=SCALE_WIDTH,
    orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
    label="exposure_compensation")
scaleExpCompensation.set(0)
scaleExpCompensation.pack(anchor=Tkinter.CENTER)

print("start")
startCamHandler()

Tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  You could have packed `previewPanel` into `tkTop` just as easily as you did `previewWin`.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it's showing error